# Transform/Scale doesn't appropriately scale background attachment fixed

Tags: html, css

I have two images which get overlayed on top of each other in my application, these are represented as `foreground` and `background`. For both of these I'm using `background-attachment: fixed` to make sure the images are always the exact same size as each other. This allows me to add an edited version on the foreground, but still keep the two images consistent so they both look like one.

You can see an example of this below;

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.background_container,
.foreground_container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}

.background,
.foreground {
  background-image: url("https://i.redd.it/uojoraeqr4c31.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}

.foreground {
  max-height: 50%;
  margin: 5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background_container">
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>


<div class="foreground_container">
  <div class="foreground"></div>
</div>
```

The issue I'm having is that I have a need to zoom these images in on an animation. To do this I'm using `transform: scale (1.5)` on a keyframe, but the more it scales, the more out of sync the two images get. I expect `foreground` to be scaled the exact same as the `background` as they are on the same plane due to `background-attachment: fixed`, but I'm guessing the required height and margin properties cause some issues.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.background_container,
.foreground_container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}

.background,
.foreground {
  background-image: url("https://i.redd.it/uojoraeqr4c31.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.foreground {
  max-height: 50%;
  margin: 5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="background_container">
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>


<div class="foreground_container">
  <div class="foreground"></div>
</div>
```

Is there any sort of solution to this? I want example 2 to look like example 1, just more zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsbin.com/nesekuxuyu/1/edit?html,css,output

See my jsbin.

Remove your foreground specific styling and add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent container. It was scaling properly however it was exceeding the bounds of it's parent container and by hiding the overflow you prevent it from distorting the bits you can see.

*Edit* In outside discussion with James I see the actual issue and am working on an appropriate solution. Scale is overridng the fixed behavior inherent in background-attachment